# The vue3 axios proxy doesnt work when run jest unit test

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, babel-jest

I'm new to jest. In my Vue3 project. I have a api.ts and there is a method like below:

```
export async function queryEntities(type: string, data: any) {
    const link = `/mdm-webclient-application/public/en-US_US/resources/mdm/${type}/query`;
    return request({
        url: link,
        method: 'put',
        data
    })
}
```

.

And axios creation is：

```
const request = axios.create({

    baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? process.env.VUE_APP_MDM_SERVER : '/api',
    headers: {
        put: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        get: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
        },
        post: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        }
    }
```

,

proxy is：

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: (process.env.VUE_APP_MDM_SERVER),
                changeOrigin: true,
                ws: true,
                pathRewrite: {
                    '^/api': ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.
when I use npm run dev. the api is fine and can get data from server.
But when I use run unit test in jest:

```
import {mount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import LocateLegalEntity from '@/views/legal-entity/LocateLegalEntity.vue'
import element from "element-plus"
import * as API from '@/apis/api'
it('query legal Entities', async () => {
        const data={
            "@type": "literal",
            "criterionName": "simpleSearch",
            "id": 0,
            "operandValues": "a",
            "operatorName": "contains"
        }
        const response = await API.queryEntities("legalentity",data)
        expect(response.status).toBe(200)
    })
```

the return code always 404. could you please have a look